# How do I access a file's ( exe or dlls) owner details using perl?

Tags: perl, file-ownership

I wanted to simply print out these details for a directory, and I wanted to write the script in perl, any insights?

Answer (score 4):

Use `stat` to get the UID of the file's owner and `getpwuid` to get the username for the ID, e.g.:

```
my $owner = getpwuid((stat)[4]);
```

Note that, if you call `getpwuid` in list context, it will return a list of values, the first of which is the username.

Comment: Is there any way , I could do something similar, but access file version?

Comment: If by "file version" you mean the version of the application used to create/open/modify the file, that information is stored within the file itself, and extracting it depends on the specific type of file.

Comment: I'm using this script only one applications, not on actual files, so I need to get the version of say an executable, how would I do that?

Comment: It depends entirely on the executable.  By convention, running the executable with the `-v`, `-V`, or `--version` switch will produce version information, but not all programs support this, and the format of the output varies between programs.

Comment: I think salem is talking about the standard Windows metadata embedded into executable files (see properties dialog in Explorer).